# Cancel active intent from activity

Tags: android, android-intent

I have this method that opens the native camera.

```
public void takePhoto(){
    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    Uri photoUri;
    photoUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE); 
    cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoUri);
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAM_REQUREST);

}
```

It is working great, but I want to be able to return to my activity if the user forgets to, or if there is something my app needs attention for. Is there a way that I can do this from my activity?

Comment: have you overridden `onActivityResult` ?

Comment: I am just having a look at some examples of this but I dont know how I can achieve this. I thought that this was only executed when there was a result (from the camera ie cancelling or taking a photo)... can you give a little more information?

Comment: you can refer this link http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`startActivityForResult()` will automatically return after the result is obtained, so after the photo is taken in this case. If you want to relaunch your app at any point, you should use `startActivity()` with your own package in the intent.

Do it like this:

```
PackageManager p = getPackageManager();
String myPackage = getApplicationContext().getPackageName();

Intent intent = p.getLaunchIntentForPackage(myPackage);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Thanks, took a while for me to integrate the answer but it works a treat.

Answer (score 0):

Override   onActivityResult in your activity

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
        Intent intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

    Log.e(TAG, "--onActivityResult MainActivity--");


    if (requestCode == CAM_REQUREST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        Uri selectedImage = intent.getData();
        Log.e(TAG, "Your image :" + selectedImage);



}


    }
```